# Java Item Not Being Removed From LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

I am working on a simple video game, and I came upon a problem pretty quickly that I couldn't fix...I have many enemies in my game, so of course they all inherit from a class `Enemy`. But when the player and the enemy collide, the enemy is not removed...Here is my code for `Entity`, `BlueEnemy`, `Controller`, and `Enemy`. I am assuming my `Player` class is okay, because it my player disappears when they collide.

Entity.java

```
package com.darksunproductions.ld47.Entities;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import com.darksunproductions.ld47.Game.Game;

public class Entity {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private Point pos;
    private double velX;
    private double velY;
    private BufferedImage icon;
    private boolean dead = false;
    private int updatesSinceDeath = -1;

    protected Game game;

    protected Entity(int x, int y, double velX, double velY, Game game, BufferedImage icon){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.velX = velX;
        this.velY = velY;
        this.game = game;
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public void setUpdatesSinceDeath(int i){
        updatesSinceDeath = i;
    }
    public int getUpdatesSinceDeath(){
        return updatesSinceDeath;
    }
    public boolean isDead(){
        return dead;
    }
    public void kill(){
        dead = true;
        updatesSinceDeath = 0;
        try{
            icon = ImageIO.read(new File("Explosion.png"));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public Point topLeft(){
        return new Point(x, y);
    }
    public Point topRight(){
        return new Point(x+icon.getWidth(), y);
    }
    public Point bottomLeft(){
        return new Point(x, y+icon.getHeight());
    }
    public Point bottomRight(){
        return new Point(x+icon.getWidth(), y+icon.getHeight());
    }
    public void setX(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y){
        this.y = y;
    }
    public double getVelX() {
        return velX;
    }
    public void setVelX(double velX) {
        this.velX = velX;
    }
    public double getVelY() {
        return velY;
    }
    public void setVelY(double velY) {
        this.velY = velY;
    }
    public BufferedImage getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }
    public void setIcon(BufferedImage icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }
}
```

BlueEnemy.java

```
package com.darksunproductions.ld47.Entities;

import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import com.darksunproductions.ld47.Game.Drawable;
import com.darksunproductions.ld47.Game.Game;

public class BlueEnemy extends Enemy implements Drawable{

    public BlueEnemy(int x, int y, double velX, double velY, Game game){
        super(x, y, velX, velY, game, null, Type.BLUE);

        try{
            setIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("Blue_Enemy.png")));
        }catch(Exception e){
            setIcon(null);
        }
    }

}
```

Controller.java

```
package com.darksunproductions.ld47.Game;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import com.darksunproductions.ld47.Entities.Enemy;
import com.darksunproductions.ld47.Entities.Entity;
import com.darksunproductions.ld47.Entities.Player;

public class Controller {

    LinkedList<Drawable> entities = new LinkedList<Drawable>();
    Game game;

    public Controller(Game g){
        game = g;
    }

    public void testCollision(int startID){
        if(entities.size() > 0){
            Entity e1 = (Entity) entities.get(startID);
            Point corner[] = new Point[4];
            corner[0] = e1.topLeft();
            corner[1] = e1.topRight();
            corner[2] = e1.bottomLeft();
            corner[3] = e1.bottomRight();
            for (int e = startID + 1; e < entities.size(); e++) {
                Entity e2 = (Entity) entities.get(e);
                for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
                    if (corner[c].x > e2.topLeft().x && corner[c].x < e2.topRight().x) {
                        if (corner[c].y > e2.topLeft().y && corner[c].y < e2.bottomLeft().y) {
                            collide(e1, e2);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void collide(Entity e1, Entity e2){
        if(e1 instanceof Player && !e1.isDead()){
            if(e2 instanceof Enemy && !e2.isDead()){
                e1.kill();
                e2.kill();
            }
        }
    }

    public void update(){
        if(entities.size() > 0){
            for(Drawable d : entities)
                d.update();
        }
    }

    public void render(Graphics g){
        if(entities.size() > 0){
            for(Drawable d : entities)
                d.render(g);
        }
    }

    public void add(Drawable d){
        entities.add(d);
    }

    public void remove(Drawable d){
        entities.remove(d);
    }

    public void remove(int i){
        entities.remove(i);
    }

    public int size(){
        return entities.size();
    }
    public int getIdOf(Entity e){
        for(int i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++){
            if(e == (Entity)entities.get(i))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public int getIdOf(Drawable d){
        Entity e = (Entity)d;
        for(int i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++){
            if(e == (Entity)entities.get(i))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Enemy.java

```
package com.darksunproductions.ld47.Entities;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import com.darksunproductions.ld47.Game.Drawable;
import com.darksunproductions.ld47.Game.Game;

public class Enemy extends Entity implements Drawable{

    public enum Type{
        BLUE
    }

    private Type type;

    public Enemy(int x, int y, double velX, double velY, Game game, BufferedImage icon, Type type){
        super(x, y, velX, velY, game, icon);
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void render(Graphics g){
        if(getIcon() != null)
            g.drawImage(getIcon(), getX(), getY(), null);
    }

    public void update(){
        if(getUpdatesSinceDeath() < 0){

            setY(getY() + (int)getVelY());

            if(getY() > 550){
                setY(-50);
                setX((int)(Math.random()*468));
            }

        }else if(getUpdatesSinceDeath() >= 0){
            setUpdatesSinceDeath(getUpdatesSinceDeath() + 1);
            if(getUpdatesSinceDeath() > 60){
                game.c.remove(this);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the problem I get when they collide:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification(LinkedList.java:778)
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(LinkedList.java:713)
    at com.darksunproductions.ld47.Game.Controller.update(Controller.java:52)
    at com.darksunproductions.ld47.Game.Game.update(Game.java:58)
    at com.darksunproductions.ld47.Game.Game.run(Game.java:78)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

Except for a small problem...when I click on `LinkedList.java:778`, Eclipse says there is no line 778 for LinkedList...

Thank you in advance for any help given...

Comment: Normally, you could use the `LinkedList`s `Iterator` and it's `remove` method to avoid this, but since you're passing responsibility around a bit, it's a little more difficult.  One thing you could do, is instead of using `game.c.remove(this);` inside `Enemy`, you could flag the `Enemy` been "removable", so that either during the update cycle or just after it, you could collect all the "removed" elements and then remove them in one step, using `removeAll` for example.  This should be done BEFORE  the render process

Comment: The Exception you are getting means you have a race condition somewhere, ie 2 threads trying to access the same list OR you are trying to remove an item is the list you are browsing...in a bad way.

Comment: In your `Controller#update` method, instead of `for(Drawable d : entities)`, you would need to grab a instance of `entities` `Iterator` and use this to loop of the entities.  Each time you call `d.update`, you would need to check if the entity should be removed or not and use the `Iterator`'s `remove` method to remove it...

Comment: Not true, mmalik. You can easily iterate over a Collection while removing its elements, provided you take proper care - either decrementing `i` after an element is removed (not doing that might even be the cause of this issue) or, if it's a LinkedList or LinkedHashMap or similar non-contiguous collection, what MadProgrammer said about iterators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`game.c.remove(this);` is a good indicator of bad design, it's not the responsibility of the entity to decide when it should be removed, only to provide information to the `Controller` which it can use

The main problem is the enhanced loop is involving the `List`'s `Iterator`, which is preventing the underlying `List` from been modified while you are iterating over it.

Instead, use the `List`s `Iterator` yourself and when the `Controller` determines that a entity has become invalidated (dead or what ever), use the `Iterator`'s `remove` method to remove it, for example

```
public void update(){
    if(entities.size() > 0){
        LinkedList<Drawable> entities = new LinkedList<>();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Drawable d = it.next();
            d.update();
            // Or what ever flag you want to use
            if (d.isRemovable()) {
                it.remove(d);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that game.c is the controller in the BlueEnemy class in which case you are looping in your controller over the same list you are potentially removing from.  This is why the concurrent modification exception.  You could loop over a copy of the list and this would be a workaround.

Comment: Seen as accessing the controller's entity list is really a bad design idea, it might be better to use the `Contoller`'s `update` method directly, grabbing the list's `Iterator`.  This way the `update` method could call `update` on the entity and then check to see if it should be removed and use the `Iterator`'s `remove` method to remove it...

Comment: I agree with madprogrammer.  Ideally you would refactor this.